# Finding the area of projected parametric surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surfaces, parametric, projection

I'm trying to find the area of parametric surface of a cylinder projected onto a plane.
The parametric equation of a cylinder is
$$S(u, v) = (r\cos(u), r\sin(u), v)$$
the equation for projecting a surface onto a plane with unitized normal vector $\overrightarrow{N}$ is:
$$S_n(u,v) = S(u,v) - \langle S(u,v),\,\overrightarrow{N}\rangle *\overrightarrow{N} $$
And finally, for calculating the area of the projection we should do the following:
$$
S_u = \frac{dS}{du}; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;S_v = \frac{dS}{dv};
$$
$$
A = \iint_D\|S_u\times S_v\|\,du\,dv
$$
But this integral is way too hard to solve like this in cartesian coordinates for arbitrary $D$ regions, I want to make a change of variables to cylindrical coordinates, such that $S(u,v)$ becomes
$$
S_{cylinder}=(r, u, v)
$$
Making the integral easier to solve, but I cant seem to find how to correctly change the integral such that the resulting area matches the real value. The usual change of coordinates method uses a Jacobian to adjust the differential terms, but in this case wouldn't the differential terms stay the same? Is it even possible to do this change of variables in this situation?

For testing I've been trying to project the half cylinder $S(u,v)$ with  $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq u\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\leq v\leq1$, onto the plane with normal vector $\overrightarrow{N} = (1, 0, 0)$ in cartesian coordinates, which has the same values for its cylindrical coordinates. The resulting area should be $2r$.

Comment: Some brainstorming comments. First, you have to take care that several points of the cylinder can have the same projection. Second, if you’re just interested in computing the area of the projection, then I suspect that finding the contours of the projection would ease the whole process.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> For your test case, the projection is parametrized by $$S_{n}(u,v)=(r\cos u, v),$$so the area is readily calculated directly (and checks with expectation). In general do you need area for "non-rectangular" regions on the cylinder?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way of doing the change of variable so I can generalize and actually use it to compute the projected shadow of a truncated cone on a plane. MATLAB cant resolve the integral in cartesian coordinates because it gets super huge, even with many assumptions, and only using the "visible" part of the cone so that it doesn't have any overlap $\langle S_u\times S_v,\, N\rangle \geq 0$, real numbers and etc.